# Удалить n-символов из ячейки

Tags: python, pandas

Как можно удалить в конкретном столбце n-последних символа из всех ячеек? (например последние 2 символа).

Пример с не удаленными символами:

```
df['s']

10
100
142
3784
74729
1837
3784917
9
```

Итог

```
df['s']

Nan (? или ноль - как правильнее?)
1
1
37
747
18
37849
Nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да в общем обычным срезом можно сделать, ну плюс косметические доделки:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'s': [10,100,142,3784,74729,1837,3784917,9]})

df['s'].astype(str).str[:-2].replace('', pd.NA)
```

Вывод:

```
0     <NA>
1        1
2        1
3       37
4      747
5       18
6    37849
7     <NA>
Name: s, dtype: object
```